# Opposite version of numpy.testing.almost_approx_equal()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, unit-testing, python-unittest

I am using `numpy.testing.assert_approx_equal(x, y, 5)` in my Python unittests to check whether `x` and `y` are equal, accurate to 5 significant figures.

**Question:** How can we do the opposite of this: to check whether `x` and `y` are not equal, accurate to 5 significant figures?

Looking for something like `Unittest.assertAlmostNotEqual` which is testing for the opposite of `Unittest.assertAlmostEqual`, but for `numpy.testing.almost_approx_equal`.

For example, the desired function

```
desired_assert_function_not_approx_equal(1234, 1230, 2)
```

should raise an `AssertionError`.

Comment: There is no `almost_approx_equal`, just `assert_almost_equal` and `assert_approx_equal`. It's not important for the answer, but for searchability, which one do you mean?

Comment: @Seb `assert_approx_equal` is the one. Updated OP.

Answer (score 2):

You could just use the fact that the testing functions raise an `AssertionError` when their conditions aren't met to create the behaviour you'd like to see:

```py
assert_raises(AssertionError, assert_approx_equal, x, y, 5)
```